# MobileFirst 7.1 How to block the user form access the mobile App

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We are using MobileFirst 7.1.0.0-MFPF-IF201705051403 version.

We found some fraudulent activity with one of our users using Mobile App. 
How do I block this user/devices from further accessing our mobile first servers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mobile application management feature to control user/device access.  See [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_device_mgmt.html) for more details.

Comment: From this documentation [https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/t_enabling_device_access_mgmt.html] It is unclear if this flag(wl.device.enableAccessManagement=true) is required to be set in worklight.properties or server.xml? Can you clarify this?

Comment: This should be set in the worklight.properties file.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_device_mgmt_performance.html

Comment: This change will block the device or the User it self. What I mean is if the user tries to use different device will it be allowed access after this change.